# “sich vergrößern” vs. “sich erweitern” with respect to land

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

> Nachdem sich das Land um französische Gebiete vergrößert hatte, bekam Französisch dieselbe Bedeutung wie Deutsch.

Can we replace the verb *vergrößern* with *erweitern* here? Is there any difference between the two verbs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Nachdem sich das Land um französisch**e** Gebiete vergrößert hatte, bekam<s>en</s> *(besser: erhielt/erlangte)* Französisch dieselbe Bedeutung wie Deutsch.

Ja, man kann an dieser Stelle auch *erweitert* einsetzen. Der Bedeutungsunterschied ist sehr klein. *Erweitern* bedeutet, etwas größer zu fassen.

> Wir erweitern den Durchfluß. *(Wir nehmen ein größeres Rohr.)*
>
> Wir erhöhen den Durchfluß. *(Wir schicken mehr durch das Rohr.)*
>
> Wir vergrößern den Durchfluß. *(beide obigen Möglichkeiten)*